# SmartGWT IntegerItem divide the displayed value / 100

Tags: smartgwt

How can I set up the displayed value of an `IntegerItem` on a Form in SmartGWT in a way that it still receives and saves it´s true value (* 100), but displays only the value divided by 100?

```
IntegerItem example = new IntegerItem("field", "example");
```

| 500 |     ->       |  5  |

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you use a `setValueFormatter`:

```
IntegerItem iItem = new IntegerItem();
iItem.setValueFormatter(new FormItemValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String formatValue(Object value, Record record, DynamicForm form, FormItem item) {
        int integerValue = Integer.parseInt(value.toString())/100;
        return String.valueOf(integerValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by using `setAttribute()` method.

Have a look at the following sample:

```
IntegerItem example = new IntegerItem("field", "example");
example.setValue(5);
example.setAttribute("trueValue", 500);

// Later on when you want to retrieve both the values
Integer displayValue = example.getValueAsInteger();
Integer trueValue = example.getAttributeAsInt("trueValue");
```